# Objective C: Need to parse an object

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a calendar object returned as

```
1:58:26 EAS-iPhone-5c InstaFeed[346] <Warning>: (
    "EKEvent <0x1658d5b0>\n{\n\t EKEvent <0x1658d5b0>\n{\t title = \t\tMeetings for surveyApp; \n\t location = \tany loacation; \n\t calendar = \tEKCalendar <0x1668d4e0> {title = Calendar; type = Exchange; allowsModify = YES; color = #A2845E;}; \n\t alarms = \t\t(\n    \"EKAlarm <0x16692740> {triggerInterval = -900.000000}\"\n); \n\t URL = \t\t\t(null); \n\t lastModified = 2014-04-28 09:43:17 +0000; \n\t timeZone = \tGMT+0530 (GMT+5:30) offset 19800 \n}; \n\t location = \tany loacation; \n\t startDate = \t2014-07-24 10:00:00 +0000; \n\t endDate = \t\t2014-07-24 10:30:00 +0000; \n\t allDay = \t\t0; \n\t floating = \t0; \n\t recurrence = \tEKRecurrenceRule <0x16694c60> RRULE FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1; \n\t attendees = \t(\n    \"EKAttendee <0x1668f2d0> {UUID = AB8950BF-702B-4E0C-9A6D-5CD1F61AA05A; name = Karthik Srinivasulu; email = ksrinivasulu@sapient.com; status = 2; role = 1; type = 1}\",\n    \"EKAttendee <0x16695e00> {UUID = A553802F-0083-497E-8D68-911864C28A03; name = Sushil Thanvi; email = sthanvi@sapient.com; status = 0; role = 1; type = 1}\",\n    \"EKAttendee <0x16695fa0> {UUID = 30E2351E-F501-42DD-B282-82D7350DC7FE; name = Sonam Chadha (X) Exit (5/6/2014); email = schadha2@sapient.com; status = 0; role = 1; type = 1}\"\n) \n};"
```

I am able to get the **title,location,notes**,and **dates** with:

```
 for (EKEvent * event in matchingEvents) {
        NSMutableDictionary *entry = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]      initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      event.title, @"title",
                                      event.location, @"location",
                                      event.notes, @"message",
                                      [df stringFromDate:event.startDate], @"startDate",
                                      [df stringFromDate:event.endDate], @"endDate",
                                       nil];
        [finalResults addObject:entry];
    }
```

I need to get the list of attendees and the organizer of the meeting. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [attendees](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKCalendarItemClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/EKCalendarItem/attendees) and [organizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/EKEvent/organizer) properties.

Comment: Sorry but i am new to objective C and after several attempts, i was unable to gt the list of attendees into variables,so on the basis of the log of the object,if somebody could share a piece of code,it would be appreciated!